# Session value are not set in PHP

Tags: php

**index.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $sql = "select * from admin where email = '$email' and password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($result)
        {
            if ($num_rows > 0) 
            {
                $sqls = "select * from admin where email = '$email' and password = '$password'";
                $results = mysqli_query($con,$sqls);
                while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) 
                {
                    $_SESSION['admin_id'] =  $rows['id'];
                }
                header ("Location: dashboard.php");
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "<p id='red'>Wrong email or password.</p>";
            }   
        }
    }
?>
```

**dashboard.php**

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    include('../config.php');
    $admin_id = $_SESSION['admin_id'];
    echo $admin_id;
?>
```

In this code I have create login form and initialize id into session variable when I echo $_SESSION['admin_id'] in index.php it return value but when I want to set $_SESSION['admin_id'] in dashboard.php but its not working or showing no value. How can I fix this issue ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Add session_start() in index.php

Comment: thanx @SaadSuri

Comment: You're wide open to SQL Injection attacks with that code, also ***NEVER*** store any user passwords in plain text form, they should ***ALWAYS*** be hashed!!!!

Comment: You should save a hashed passsword and not the entered password directly. you could use `password_hash` for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add   session_start();  to the top of index.php  (inside the php tags of course)

```
 session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the session_start() already initialized in the index.php file? You should check that first. It's recommended that you place this in top of all files or a single included file in your script.

```
session_start();
```

Test if this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before set or get session in php you should always start session at the top of the page like below

```
session_start();
```

So in your code try to to start session in index.php

Answer (score 0):

Add `session_start()` in **index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $sql = "select * from admin where email = '$email' and password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($result)
        {
            if ($num_rows > 0) 
            {
                $sqls = "select * from admin where email = '$email' and password = '$password'";
                $results = mysqli_query($con,$sqls);
                while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) 
                {
                    $_SESSION['admin_id'] =  $rows['id'];
                }
                header ("Location: dashboard.php");
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "<p id='red'>Wrong email or password.</p>";
            }   
        }
    }
?>
```